# Using Conda to package a set of JARS

Tags: java, jar, packaging, conda

I am trying to package a set of JAR files into a single conda package.  The reason is so I can push this package to an internal conda repository, and then use conda to manage deployment.   My conda.recipe/meta.yaml looks like this

```
package:
  name: my_java_apps
  version: 0.0.0

source:
  path: ../build/allJars
```

When I run

> conda build conda.recipe/meta.yaml

I get a .bz2 file generated.  However when I look inside that file (decompress it), I don't see any of my JARs...I only see conda recipe related files (i.e. info/ folder).

My folder structure is as follows:

```
project_root/
            build/allJars <---- this contains all jars
            conda.recipe/meta.yaml  <---- my conda recipe file.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I would guess your build script needs to be something like `cp *.jar $PREFIX/path/to/place/you/want/to/put/the/jar/files`, although I'm not totally sure where the files will be put when you install the package (hence, not an answer). `$PREFIX` is an environment variable defined during conda-building that points to the environment that's been created for the build.

Comment: By the way, nice title! :-)

Comment: Thanks!  That worked.   Could you please post that as an answer so I can mark it as such?

Comment: I think it would be better if you posted the complete answer (including your meta.yaml and/or build.sh). Although my comment pointed the way, I think you should put the answer, since you have all of the information and I would have to guess about some of it :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @darthbith for the tip.  Here's the working solution:

```
package:
  name: my_java_apps
  version: 0.0.0

source:
  path: ../build/allJars

build:
  script: mkdir -p $PREFIX/jars && cp *.jar $PREFIX/
```

As a bonus (outside the scope of this question, but including it here), I wanted to have this run as a Gradle task.  The below task runs conda build and outputs the artifacts to a subfolder within my project.

```
task createCondaPackage(type: Exec) {
    commandLine "mkdir", "$buildDir/conda"
    commandLine "conda", "build", "conda.recipe/meta.yaml", "--output-folder", "$buildDir/conda"
}
```

After running the above gradle task, the conda package can be found under build/conda sub folder.

```
project_root/
            build/allJars <---- this contains all jars
            build/conda   <---- this contains conda package
            conda.recipe/meta.yaml  <---- my conda recipe file.
```